# An attempt was made to access an exiting process

Tags: windows, windows-10, rename, kill

We have a directory that we cannot delete because...

> Cannot remove item C:\myDir: The process cannot access the file 'C:\myDir\' because it is being used by another process.

Inside Resource Monitor > CPU > Associated Handles, a search for `myDir` shows that `cmd.exe` is using our directory.

Inside [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), running as administrator, our attempts to terminate `cmd.exe` are met with this:

> Unable to terminate cmd.exe (PID 4656): An attempt was made to access an exiting process.

Beyond restarting the computer, how else can we kill this process and thereby delete or rename our directory?

Comment: You could try [IObit Unlocker](http://www.iobit.com/en/iobit-unlocker.php)

Comment: @DavidPostill IObit Unlocker did not work. I tried unlock and delete. Unlocker said, "Status: Unlock & Delete successfully." The directory is still there. Odd.

Comment: Relevant: [In windows, do file-locks stay after a process was terminated via taskkill?](http://superuser.com/q/918476)

Comment: Looks like a restart is required then.

Comment: You could also try [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/)

Comment: Yep; Windows is bugged and won't let the process finish exiting so a reboot is the only way to get rid of it.

Comment: try deleting in safe-mode.

Comment: The error message you saw, "An attempt was made to access an exiting process", is the MessageText for the MessageId `STATUS_PROCESS_IS_TERMINATING`, which is NTSTATUS 0xC000010A. All this is according to the "ntstatus.h" header file, which is included in the Windows SDK.

Comment: I don't believe that this is a duplicate of the other question of which it is marked as a duplicate. They are different error messages and caused by different things. What tipped me off was that you were using Process Hacker (which is also what I was having a problem with).

I closed and re-opened process hacker and the process had closed.
So quite possibly it's worth doing that first. It's not the first time it had happened on my server which had a program running and process hacker running for at least a few months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be an unkillable process.  Try a Google search for [ [`unkillable process`](https://www.google.com/search?q=unkillable+process) ], or check out the thread ["How can I kill an unkillable process?"](https://superuser.com/questions/136272/unkillable-process-problem) and the solutions mentioned there.  Or, as you mentioned, you could restart the machine.

Comment: In my question a duplicate of the answer to which you referred me?

Comment: Your question is indeed a duplicate of the unkillable-process question. But Jeff Atwood [writes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) on the official Stack Exchange blog that some duplication is good, and I agree.